# Bokeh Figure won't Update?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm new to Bokeh and was wondering if anyone could lend a little help tell me why my plot is not updating? The code is very simple, and can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/MLAigEG6

The code is just supposed to grab some data using the function "get_dataset", plot a bar chart, and let me update the plot using a dropdown box and slider. The two small dataframes can be found here:

https://github.com/degravek/bdata

The slider is set to default at 15 (30 total values plotted). If the slider is moved, or if the dropdown box is changed, the axes for the plot don't update for some reason. For example, if the slider is set to 2, there should only be 2 bars shown, and the axes should adjust accordingly. Thanks a lot for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice code. In your update function, you also need to update the `x_range.factors` of the plot. And `global asdata` is not needed here.

```
def update_samples_or_dataset(attrname, old, new):
    dataset = dataset_select.value
    n_samples = int(samples_slider.value)

    asdata = get_dataset(dataset, n_samples)
    plot.x_range.factors = asdata['aspects'].tolist() # this was missing
    source.data = dict(x=asdata['aspects'].tolist(), y=asdata['importance'].values)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I had one more quick question. Do you know how to use a "custom" function in Bokeh using the Bokeh server? For example, can you plot using

    def mplot(source):
        p = pd.DataFrame()
        p['aspects'] = source.data['x']
        p['importance'] = source.data['y']
        plot = Bar(p, values='importance', label='aspects', legend=False)
        return plot

My current attempt is here:

http://pastebin.com/7Zk9ampq

but it doesn't run. I'm not worried about getting the function "update_samples_or_dataset" to work, just the initial plot to show. Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you also provided the missing data: sorted_ngram3.csv, sorted_chunk.csv, and sorted_rake.csv. But in general you should create a simple example with few data points and few details, just to test your code.